# Predictive analysis of future sales using historical data

Tags: sql-server, machine-learning, data-mining

I do descriptive analytics and reporting at a company that sells a wide range of products. We record sales transactions and everytime an item is sold, the following is recorded:

```
Customer ID (each customer has a unique ID)
Product ID (each product has a unique ID)
Sale date
```

(Other fields are recorded too - location of purchase, quantity, payment type, etc.)

We sell a few big ticket items, and what I'm wondering is if it's possible to predict whether a customer will buy one of the big ticket items based on their purchase history, using transactional data as described above. We have about 2 million rows of sales data spanning seven years, and in that time maybe 14,000 big ticket items have been sold to 5,000 out of 50,000 customers.

I use SQL Server 2008 R2 which has the data mining feature. I did some brief reading on it but can't figure out what model would be best, or if it's something that's even doable. Can someone point me in the right direction to get started?

Comment: Forget SQL Server "data mining". SQL Server to data mining is as MS Paint from Win 3.11 is to Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the SQL server data mining feature is useful.  I took a look at the one for SQL 2012 and decided it wasn't.

As for your prediction, this would be a supervised learning problem (just pick any simple algorithm), where each customer is a row and your features would be the different products.  Your positive labels then would then be the rows of customers that had bought big ticket items.

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is called sequential pattern mining and the specific technique that you are looking for is called [discrete event prediction](https://www.aaai.org/Papers/AAAI/1992/AAAI92-021.pdf). However with that being said, I don't think you will be able to do what you want to do with an out of the box solution on sql server.